Can't get RewriteCond right in .htaccess
I'm trying to redirect some urls, but RewriteCond is not working. What am I doing wrong?
URLs I try to redirect:
https://kotrabatowy.pl/kod-rabatowy/*/test1
https://kotrabatowy.pl/kod-rabatowy/*/test2
to
https://kotrabatowy.pl/kod-rabatowy/*/
but exclude urls with 3-4 numbers, like:
https://kotrabatowy.pl/kod-rabatowy/*/123
https://kotrabatowy.pl/kod-rabatowy/*/1234
The rules I used were:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^kod-rabatowy/([^/]+)/[0-9]{3,4}/$
RewriteRule ^kod-rabatowy/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ kod-rabatowy/$1/ [R=301,L,NC]


I would suggest some light modifications to your implementation attempt:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/kod-rabatowy/([^/]+)/[0-9]{3,4}/?$
RewriteRule ^kod-rabatowy/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ kod-rabatowy/$1/ [R=301,L,NC]

There were two issues with your RewriteCond:

The %{REQUEST_URI} variable always contains the absolute path that has been requested, even when implemented inside distributed configuration files (typically called ".htaccess"). Adding a leading slash ("/") allows the condition's pattern to get matched.
Your RewriteCond and also your RewriteRule have a trailing slash ("/") in their matching pattern, however the requested URLs you provide as an example do not have such a trailing slash. If you make that trailing slash optional (using the "?" operator) you can allow the pattern to match both cases, with or without trailing slash.

I'd also say that this could be simplified further:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/\d{3,4}/?$
RewriteRule ^/?kod-rabatowy/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ kod-rabatowy/$1/ [R=301,L]


Since your RewriteRule matching pattern already makes sure the rule only gets applied if the right path structure is requested you do not have to repeat that pattern in the RewriteCond. Leaving it away allows to concentrate that condition on just the trailing numbers which is what you actually want to check with that condition.
The character sequence [0-9] can be replaced by a \d which is more compact and more clear in it's expression.
Coding an optional leading slash (/?) in your rule's matching pattern allows the rule to work identically regardless of whether it is implemented in a distributed configuration file or in the central configuration, so where your virtual host actually is configured (which is often the better place to implement such rules for various reasons). Keep in mind that the matching pattern of a RewriteCond is matched against the relative path of the request when implemented in a distributed configuration file but against the absolute requested path when implemented in a central configuration file. That is documented behavior. And it actually does make a lot of sense.

You can play around with that a bit on a htaccess file validator.

It works! Thank you very much for your help.

I hope it does ;-) The important step for you now is NOT to blindly copy this, but to actually understand why it works. That is why I added the explanations. You definitely should also start looking into the documentation of the apache modules.

I am learning, so the explanations were the best part of your answer :) Thank you once more.
